# Where with OR condition for the same column in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to retrieve all records that have `expired_at` as nil and `expired_at` greater than the current time.

I've tried this:

```
PriceRule.where("expired_at > ? OR expired_at = ?", DateTime.now, nil)
```

But that is only returning me the records `expired_at` greater than `DateTime.now`. Why is the `nil` being neglected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current query checks that `expired_at` is equal to null (via `= NULL`) which will not evaluate to true. Instead, you want to query that the column is a null value by using `IS NULL`.

Therefore, the query can be tweaked to the following:

```rb
PriceRule.where("expired_at > ? OR expired_at IS NULL", DateTime.now)
```

Or, if you wish to keep your original argument structure, you can pass `nil` as before:

```rb
PriceRule.where("expired_at > ? OR expired_at IS ?", DateTime.now, nil)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also take advantage of Rails [`or`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#or-conditions) here, which will take care of having `IS NULL` instead of `= NULL`. I would also recommend using [`Time.current`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html#method-c-current) instead, which has better support for time zones.

```
PriceRule
  .where(expired_at: Time.current..)
  .or(PriceRule.where(expired_at: nil))
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use the following syntax as well

```
PriceRule
.where(expired_at: DateTime.now..)
.or(PriceRule.where(expired_at: nil))
```